# How to update list view with compass heading like google places application in android

Tags: android, geolocation, heading

I am trying to display an arrow pointing towards destination locations on list view,I did this by calculating bearing between current and destination,but I need to update the arrow 
when user rotates his device and as well as when user location changes,can anyone help me in doing this.Thanks...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833654/android-compass-distance-in-a-listview/6639974#6639974